# how to visualize the direction of a moving gameobject as a vector in the scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I have a moving game object and i want to visualize the direction of its velocity as an arrow ( vector ) ,
I could not find a function that enables me to show that vector in the scene !

Vector3 direction ;
and i'm stuck finding method to show this vector in the scene .

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html you can draw line to use Debug.DrawLine

Comment: By visualize in the scene you mean just for YOU for debugging purposes in the scene view or in the game view to the USER?

Comment: i mean in the game view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you're looking for a simple gizmo to visualise the velocity vector. In that case, you could use `OnDrawGizmos()` to draw it and then enable Gizmos within Game view using the Gizmos toggle located at the right-most of the window:

[image: Game View Gizmos toggle]

For the code itself, you could use `Handles.ArrowHandleCap` to visualise a `Rigidbody`'s velocity as follows:

```cs
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class VelocityVisualizer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The length of the arrow, in meters
    [SerializeField] [Range(0.5F, 2)] private float arrowLength = 1.0F;

    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (!Application.isPlaying) return;

        var position = transform.position;
        var velocity = _rigidbody.velocity;

        if (velocity.magnitude < 0.1f) return;

        Handles.color = Color.red;
        Handles.ArrowHandleCap(0, position, Quaternion.LookRotation(velocity), arrowLength, EventType.Repaint);
    }
}
```

Attach this script as a component of a game object that has a `Rigidbody`, and it will display its velocity direction using an arrow

[image: Visualisation of a velocity arrow gizmo]